# Adding privateNetworkClientServer capability to Windows 8 Cordova Application

Tags: cordova, windows-8, manifest, capability

How / where do I add the privateNetworkClientServer capability to my Cordova application so that it ends up in the compiled Windows 8 app manifest file.  If i build, modify the built application manifest to ass the capability manually it is lost the second i press play as it overwrites the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I found the answer, you need to create a package.manifest file in res\cert\windows8

I then copied all of the fields from manifest that was built prior with exception of the Build:MetaData element, and added my desired capability to the existing list.

Now when I compile it uses package.manifest as the base and I get my capability.  Bit of a hack if you ask me, a simple section in Config.xml would suffice.