# Windows Phone Capabilities with Cordova

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, capability

I have problems with the capabilities of the windows phone according to UDP Socket Access.

I know that i have to set up the capabilities "internetClientServer" and "privateNetworkClientServer" 
(see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx)

But I dont know where I have to setup the manifest file where these capabilities should be inserted. I found a older question with a similar problem but thats not working. 
(see:[Adding privateNetworkClientServer capability to Windows 8 Cordova Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930856/adding-privatenetworkclientserver-capability-to-windows-8-cordova-application))

I extended the UDP Plugin "in.girish.datagram" with the Windows Phone Part and adapt the according plugin.xml file with the following lines. (only the capability part)

```
      <config-file target="res/cert/windows8/AppxManifest.xml" parent="/Package/Capabilities">
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
  </config-file>
```

I think the target information is wrong but i dont know what is the right one. It would be very nice if somebody knows a solution.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what my problem is, the capabilities internetClientServer and privateNetworkClientServer should be inserted into the package.appxmanifest file which is only available inside Windows Phone 8.1 solutions.

In windows phone 8 solutions this file is named WMAppManifest.

see this articel about the difference of the package.appxmanifest and the wmappmanifest file:
http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/07/wp80-vs-wp81-all-about.html

Comment: According to the docs, in Windows Phone `internetClient` = `internetClientServer` = `privateNetworkClientServer` so you just need one of them (presumably `internetClientServer` which is what the appxmanifest designer in VS generates). Were you actually able to access private network IPs though? No matter what I did I was blocked when trying to access (using `HttpClient`) IP addresses directly, but accessing domains worked. Related thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4fda36c-5497-42bb-99e8-170a8de871e0/ip-addresses-not-allowed-with-httpclientgetasync?forum=winappswithcsharp