# Cordova manifest capability for windows platform

Tags: windows, cordova, manifest, capability

We are developing an Window Store App with Cordova and trying to authenticate user against Windows Serve AD. There is a capability "Enterprise Authentication" need to be set on package.windows.appxmanifest. We can do it direct from VS2015 RC, however this file will be overwritten every time Cordova build.
We've tried to following this:
[Windows Phone Capabilities with Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960806/windows-phone-capabilities-with-cordova) and this: [Adding privateNetworkClientServer capability to Windows 8 Cordova Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930856/adding-privatenetworkclientserver-capability-to-windows-8-cordova-application)
but could not success.
Did we miss something or somebody point us to the right direction? Cordova document is not help much.
Thank you in advance.
Configuration:
Windows Store App
Windows 8.1
Cordova 5.1.1

Comment: Use this plugin: https://github.com/dilhan2013/cordova-windows-capability-localnetwork

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way was to write your own Cordova plugin.

I created a plugin.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
 <name>Windows Add privateNetworkClientServer Capability</name>
 <description>Add privateNetworkClientServer Capability to appxmanifest</description>

<!-- windows8 -->
<platform name="windows8">
    <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities">
       <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Comment: I have created a plugin for this using Adam's code. https://github.com/dilhan2013/cordova-windows-capability-localnetwork